# Datatables oSelectorOpts option based on condition

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm exporting all the data from datatables.Now what I need is I have a condition if the condition is true enable `oSelectorOpts` otherwise not.

Here is my config code:

```
"aButtons": [
    {
       "bFooter": false,
       "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig ) {
        if(condition)
        {
           "oSelectorOpts": { page: 'current' };
        }
    },
'sExtends':'xls',
"sFileName": "Telephone_Directory.xls",
'mColumns':[0,1,2,3] 
},
```

Why I need this is some times I'll export all the data and some time current page data only.
Is there any other way to achieve this.suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I use which gives you 2 buttons/options, print current page or print all:

```
  "sDom": '<"clear">T<"clear">lfrtip',
  "oTableTools": {
    "aButtons": [
      {
        "sExtends": "print",
        "sButtonText": "print page",
        "bShowAll": false
      },
      {
        "sExtends": "print",
        "sButtonText": "print all",
        "bShowAll": true
      }
    ],
    "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.0/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
  },
```